# Generate JSON data from Json Schema V3 in Java

Tags: json, jsonschema, generate

Could you please let me know how to Generate **JSON data from Json Schema V3 in Java**. Is there any Java library for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what is officially known. If you find others, please submit a pull request.

https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#generators-from-schemas